# virtualbox 5.0.20 on win 7 32 bit

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to use virtual box 5.0.20 on window 7 32 bit. I need to create Ubuntu 64bit VM. But fail to open session error occurs. I can't start my VM. I hope somebody here can help with my problem. I'm very new to V box. Please advise me!

Comment: What does the error say? Have you checked virtualization is enabled in BIOS?

Comment: the error is as follow...The virtual machine 'ubt' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\lenovo\VirtualBox VMs\ubt\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

Comment: I have enabled virtualization too. I also tried VBoxDrv method. The problem is still here

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a 64-bit virtual machine on a 32-bit OS. There is a good [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7/866963#866963) on *superuser* about it.
You must use a Ubuntu 32-bit image with your OS.

Comment: yes! I realize that and try that too. In error log, it said error loading to crypt32.dll.  thanks for answer.